# Indexing Latex&MD files with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, latex, markdown

I'm trying to index a lot of latex and markdown files which are in different folders using elasticsearch **from command line.**

So far I haven't been able to find a tutorial which gives me detailed information on how to do it.

Is there anyone with ElasticSearch that could help me out? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting files is easy with [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html).

But what are you trying to achieve? Capturing the full LaTeX file or just the raw text?
If you're only after the raw text, I'd use [Detex](https://github.com/pkubowicz/opendetex) and you can actually call it from [Logstash with the exec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-exec.html). Should be pretty straight forward.